# An error occured submitting the edit

Tags: bug

I tried to edit this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35830699/edit
to fix some errors and SO does not let me save the edit.

The whole post I tried to submit can be read here
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/190ff370f2171ba05a50

I have seen other questions like this and there was the comment to create a new question and tag it as `bug` as there should be no code that is not postable on SO.

Comment: I tried to edit your answer with the exact code from your gist. Is it the way you wanted? Do you get an error while submitting?

Comment: I guess it's something on your side: some security software that is tracking all the outgoing requests, and when detecting something suspicious, blocking the request. Try using ssl, i.e. follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35830699/edit) to edit, and see if it works. If not, temporary disable whatever security software you have, and see if it helps.

Comment: Patrick, I have overwritten your answer to test what Shadow Wizard suggested.
@ShadowWizard thank you, you are really right, which is really interesting and cool to know! If you add your comment as an answer I will select it as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This odd behavior can be explained by a security software on your side (either your own machine, or in the network), that is tracking all the outgoing requests, and when detecting something suspicious, blocking the request. (Usually to block viruses and malware.)

I would try doing the following:

- Using ssl, i.e. follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35830699/edit) to edit, and see if it works. Most security programs will leave ssl requests alone.
- If no luck, temporary disable whatever security software you have, and see if it helps. If you're part of network, contact the network admin and ask him/her to do it, explaining what's at stake.